# Search Performance of Elasticsearch index with large documents (PDF’s)

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm fairly new to Elasticsearch and would like some help with tuning and tips on how to increase the performance of my index.

Currently i have around 4500 documents in the index and a size on disc about 34GB that consists of PDF's with some metadata. The PDF's are indexed using the Mapper Attachment plugin and are from 10MB to 150MB each, some are bigger up to 250MB.

My problem is that search operations take long time, sometimes up to multiple seconds, i'm filtering on up to 0 - 7 fields, ordering on 2 plus a Query String query against the documents text (base64 encoded), title, and some other meta fields. Im also using pagination for all of the results (up to 450 pages of 10 documents each) and highlighting to show what part that was hit. I guess this is part of my problem but i can't really get away from it.

The server got 8GB of RAM and ElasticSearch has the ES_HEAP_SIZE set to 2GB, i'm guessing this is the other part of my problem and that the bottleneck is here, right? Don't know how much i can increase it either since it's running a web server as well. Server can of course be upgraded.

I haven't changed any settings regarding shards from the default values. It's currently hosted in Azure but i don't know right now if i got SSD's or spinning disc's

I'm not surprised that it does but i would like to understand why

What can i do to improve my performance?

As requested this is a sample query.

```
{
"index": "publications",
"body": {
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        [{
                            "range": {
                                "pubdate": {
                                    "gte": "2010-01-01T00:00:00",
                                    "lte": "2016-01-01T00:00:00"
                                }
                            }
                        }, {
                            "term": {
                                "author": "daniel"
                            }
                        }, {
                            "term": {
                                "title": "rock"
                            }
                        }]
                    ]
                }
            },
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "fields": [
                        ["title", "author", "files.data", "articleId"]
                    ],
                    "query": "Hard"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "title": {},
            "author": {},
            "articleId": {},
            "exact_articleId": {},
            "files.data": {}
        }
    },
    "sort": {
        "date": {
            "order": "desc"
        },
        "_score": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    },
    "size": 10,
    "from": 0,
    "fields": ["id", "title", "pubdate", "orderable", "articleId", "author", "languages", "types", "exact_title", "files.file", "files.name", "bibas_date"],
    "_source": ["files.file", "files.name"]
}
```

}

And this is my mapping

```
{
"publications": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
        "publication": {
            "properties": {
                "articleId": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": true,
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_standard_whitespace"
                },
                "author": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": true,
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_standard",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "date": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "store": true,
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                },
                "created": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "store": true,
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                },
                "exact_articleId": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": true,
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword"
                },
                "exact_title": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": true,
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword"
                },
                "files": {
                    "properties": {
                        "data": {
                            "type": "attachment",
                            "path": "full",
                            "fields": {
                                "data": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "store": true,
                                    "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                                    "analyzer": "analyzer_standard_whitespace"
                                },
                                "author": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "title": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "name": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "date": {
                                    "type": "date",
                                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                                },
                                "keywords": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "content_type": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "content_length": {
                                    "type": "integer"
                                },
                                "language": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "description": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "store": true
                        },
                        "file": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "store": true,
                            "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword"
                        },
                        "name": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "store": true,
                            "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "store": true
                },
                "keywords": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": true,
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword"
                },
                "languages": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": true,
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword"
                },
                "orderable": {
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "store": true
                },
                "pubdate": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "store": true,
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                },
                "title": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": true,
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_standard",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "types": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": true,
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword"
                },
                "updated": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "store": true,
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "creation_date": "1451478916341",
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "analyzer_standard_whitespace": {
                        "filter": "lowercase",
                        "tokenizer": "whitespace"
                    },
                    "analyzer_standard": {
                        "filter": "lowercase",
                        "tokenizer": "standard"
                    },
                    "analyzer_keyword": {
                        "filter": "lowercase",
                        "tokenizer": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "number_of_shards": "5",
            "uuid": "PjlrtJUUT1CrGduRpxPETw",
            "version": {
                "created": "1070399"
            },
            "number_of_replicas": "1"
        }
    },
    "warmers": {}
}
```

}

Comment: I would split all PDFs into single pages (can be easily done with [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) and similar tools) and store each page in a different ES document, that would certainly be way faster.

Comment: @vlad.golubev the details are almost insufficient. What is the query, what tests were performed, was the performance monitored in any way, what the logs show, where is the bottleneck, what's the mapping, all the nodes' settings etc. This is a very open ended post.

Comment: I agree with you @AndreiStefan . Nevertheless Val's comment is valid and also clearing up bottleneck in such use cases is essential. But I'm still voting to close it a too broad to answer. (ps it can't be closed due to the bounty) :/

Comment: I would also increase `ES_HEAP_SIZE` to 4GB since you have 8GB you can safely give one half to ES. But definitely split your PDFs and index a single page per document, I had a similar use case once and it turned out to be working great, but as as @AndreiStefan said, we're still missing a lot of info to properly help you.

Comment: Is there any specifics that i can update the question with? I can of course post the query but can't find any logs with performance information and no test are performed. 

About increasing the ES_HEAP_SIZE i'm a bit uncertain since i have websites on the same machine, maybe il just have to upgrade it.

Comment: Any logs that refer to long old garbage collection going on? Maybe grep the logs for `[old][gc]`. Also, do you have swapping enabled? Do you have `mlockall` set to `true` in `elasticsearch.yml`?

Comment: Also, do you have any monitoring tool (head, kopf, marvel etc)? How is the memory usage (the heap usage)?

Comment: Another question: you say "operations take long time, sometimes up to multiple seconds". Which take multiple seconds and which take less? It's the same exact query (with `size` and `from`)?

Comment: Can you also share your mapping type, i.e. what you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/publications` ?

Comment: @Val Updated with mapping aswell.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I would say that most queries take atleast 1 - 2 secounds. that includes the one above without filters. The query above also goes from 1,6 to 4,1 secounds when i remove the range filter. All results as displayed paginated with each page being 10 items.

Comment: @user3884316 can you provide in a gist the output of `GET /_nodes/stats`? And, also, a complete log file for one day? Which ES version is this?

Comment: I would start with [scroll api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html). Second thing I would check is operations on base64 fields (plugin itself could cause troubles). Third is volume of index generated on base64 field, check it's size is reasonable for text data in documents

Comment: @AndreiStefan This is a result from the /_nodes/stats https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b231d3b3dfa57ee8647f9d26b256eeb8 and im using ElasticSearch 1.7.3 i will get back with the log.

Comment: @pkhlop thanks but the documentation clearly states that the scroll api is not intended for real time user requests and that it should be used if you want to scroll over documents regardless of order, but i'm dealing with user requests and the order is crucial so unfortunately it's not a solution.

Comment: @user3884316 I think the size of the documents is the big problem. From those stats - `"fetch_total": 26065,
     "fetch_time_in_millis": 33175370,` shows that one fetch operation takes 1.27 seconds. After ES performs it's search in the search phase, it needs to gather the actual documents that matched the query and will issue another request to the shards that hold those documents to get them. This is called the `fetch` phase. For you this phase takes an awful lot of time. Given the size of the documents you have, that's the likely reason.

Comment: So, following my statement about `fetch` above, I would follow @Val's suggestion and index the documents page by page. If, instead, you take out the highlighting from the query (especially the one on `"files.data"`) do your response times improve?

Comment: [This](https://blog.ambar.cloud/making-elasticsearch-perform-well-with-large-text-fields/) can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try excluding the large field (data) from _source. I think it will definitely solve your issue.

Comment: I don't have data included anywhere besides the query_string query where it's needed for searching against the information in the files.

Comment: You have the data field in the source in mapping. To exclude it from mapping  add something like this: "_source": {
                        "excludes": [
                            "files.data.data"
                        ]
                    }.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question, removing the data that i want to search is not a solution.

Comment: @Umo you still can search throught that data, you didn't remove the data from index. You just store it in other way. Just try.

Comment: Iv'e read up some and understand what you are proposing. That could work, thank you. Can't test it right now though, will have to wait a couple of months until i'm done with my current project.